# Enforce to avoid self enclosing tags

Tags: xml, web-services, soap

I want to know if there is a way to force the soap response not to use self-enclosing tags even if there is no content.

For Example, I want

```
<xsd:string xsi:type="xsd:string" id="ID_4"></xsd:string>
```

instead of

```
<xsd:string id="ID_4" xsi:type="xsd:string" />
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What language and toolkits are you using to generate the output?

Comment: I use Java. I know both of the above tags are same. But unfortunately the clients using our webservice are so written that they dont recognize this self closing tag. I need to generate it this way only
     <xsd:string xsi:type="xsd:string" id="ID_4"></xsd:string>

Comment: What web services toolkit are you using? How do you serialize the response? You might be able to write a custom serializer that overrides your toolkit's default one. (P.S.: Your clients are doing it wrong. Hit them with a stick.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They two are semantically identical - they mean *exactly* the same thing.

The XML standard even says that these two are interchangeable.

Any conformant XML parser will not care which one you use - why do you?

Comment: My guess: regular expressions (and no, I am not advocating that).